# What is the default home page of SharePoint 2010 team site?

Tags: 2010, site, wiki-pages

I am working in SharePoint 2010.

Site Collection feature: *SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure* **Activated**

When I am creating a couple of new subsite with **Team Site** template.

Mostly new subsite created with default home page is **Home.aspx** (wiki Page) sitepages/home.aspx.

Sometimes new subsite created with default home page is the **default.aspx** (WebPart page) web page in the virtual root of the site.

What is the reason team site created with a default home page is **default.aspx**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`home.aspx` is present in the site pages library. Site pages library is created when you activate the `Wiki home page` feature which also updates the site welcome page to `home.aspx`.

So if this feature is not activated I think it will give you the `default.aspx` as home page.

Team Sites on SharePoint 2010 start with the "Wiki Home page" feature activated, which creates a Site Pages library and sets the Home.aspx as the default home page. So i dont think that is the issue here, could be something else at your end.

Comment: Yes, you correct some time "Wiki Page Home Page" feature not activating when creating the Team site, but sometimes it will get activated as expected. I need to check what is an issue with SP server.